# Why I can't import .babylon file to the babylon JS?

Tags: google-chrome, http, babylonjs

When i tried to import babylon file, i received the error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myfilepath' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:
I have no idea on CORS, and please help me by briefing it to the beginner level.

1)Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/AJDA/Documents/Palatisation/web%20files/box.babylon' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

2)BJS - [17:27:13]: Unable to import meshes from box.babylon: importMesh of undefined from undefined version: undefined, exporter version: undefinedimportMesh has failed JSON parse
m._ErrorEnabled @ babylon.js:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this is unfortunate but this is a security constraint enforced by browsers. Files can only be served from a webserver (like apache, IIS, etc...) from your localhost

Comment: oh thank you solved my first error but the second one BJS is still live...

Comment: Do you have a repro somewhere?

Comment: oh sorry.. i have cleared that error with the help of my seniors. thank u David

Comment: I know this is an older post but I'm having the same issue and stumbled on this post.  I'm trying to test locally (chrome) and I get the same error.  What was the solution? I tried using a url from my aws 'bucket'(storage) but still get the error :(